# How to persist Enable-PSRemoting in powershell

Tags: windows, bash, powershell, powershell-3.0

I am able to enable remoting using below command

"Enable-PSRemoting -Force".

But after restarting machine,  enable remoting is going off and need to enable it again using above command.

Is there any way to persist PSRemoting enable?

Actual my requirement contains

1. Connecting remote machine
2. Executing few commands
3. Restarting remote machine
4. connect remote machine again
5. Execute few more commands.

The above all steps needs to be done in single script.

I am not able to connect my remote machine after restart as its settings(Enable-remoting) is going off.

Comment: This is not a PowerShell code issue, which is what we are here to help with. This is an environment issue. What this sounds like is that your IT team have a GPO forced set to not allow this. Ask them, as there is no other reason I can think of that would cause this.

Comment: If it is blocked by GPO, which looks like it is, most cmdlets can be executed remotely without using WinRM or PowerShell Remoting. They come with the `-ComputerName` switch which can take a single computer or an array of computers as arguments. Alternately, you can always use `PSEXEC.exe` to turn on Powershell Remoting on remote machine.

Comment: Make sure your network adapter is not detected as ["Unidentified Network"](https://serverfault.com/q/9376/62182), in particular it needs a default gateway.